# Changing Global Website Highlight Color in CSS Only Highlighting Parts of Page

Tags: html, css

When I changed the highlight color in CSS for my site via ::selection, if I pressed CTRL + A, some parts of the page weren't the color.  Help please?  I tried putting the whole page in a div wrapper, but it didn't help.  Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I added

```
img.webpage-logo::selection{
background-color: none;     
}
```

and it worked...?  When I added more styling, it stopped working.  Before, I was confused.  Now I'm dumbfounded.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>webpage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <img class="webpage-logo" src="Images/Header/Logo/webpage-logo.png">
    <img src="Images/Header/Search/search-icon.png">
    <img src="Images/Content/Button/get-started-button.png">
    <img src="Images/Content/Share/sharing.png">
    <img src="Images/Content/Share/sharing-highlight.png">
    <img src="Images/Form/Arrow/arrow.png">
    <img src="Images/Form/Background/form-background.png">
    <img src="Images/Form/Spam/check.png">
    <img src="Images/Form/Spam/check-box.png">
    <img src="Images/Form/Submit/submit-button.png">
    <img src="Images/Footer/Logo/footer-webpage-logo.png">
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*browser text selection*/

::-moz-selection {
       background-color: #e75b5b;
       color: #505050;
}


::selection{
       background-color: #e75b5b;
       color: #5a5a5a;
}


/**THIS WORKED...HOWWWWWWWW??!?!??!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!!??**/

img.webpage-logo::selection{
    background-color: none;     
}


/*actual website.....*/

    body{
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
}
```

Comment: ^adding a * didn't seem to work

Comment: have you noticed that you are missing `<html>` begin tag? Also, your css is working for me in opera. Which browser are you using?

Comment: the trouble is when I position my elements.  There is the red highlight color, the color I chose (is that good color [off-topic, I know]), and then the default blue is in these little cracks.  I don't know where the cracks come from, or how to get rid of them